# How to find artifacts dependencies in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

In Biztalk, many artifacts (e.g. schema, pipeline etc) are used in some location like sendport, receivelocation etc.

Each time when we want to deploy an update version to Biztalk, it will said the artifact is being used. But we dont know where it is being used and we need to check all receivelocations, sendports and other places one by one.

Is there any faster approach such that we can know where the artifact is used?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi hosir, which version of BizTalk are you running? In BizTalk 2013 it's easy to see dependencies in the properties window.

Comment: Thx. We are using 2006R2

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the update you are doing involves modifying resources (DLLs)? Are you sure that all of your send ports/receive locations/orchestrations are unenlisted/disabled and that there are no more running/dehydrated orchestrations?

Comment: Yes, but is there any efficient way to find out all related sendports/receivelocations which are used by the artifacts which we want to be replaced? Currently we need to check one-by-one to see which one need to be unenlisted. thx

Answer (score 1):

[BizTalk documenter](https://biztalk2013documenter.codeplex.com/) might be of some use.  It documents in what ports a map is used.  (Full Disclosure: I am now a developer on the latest versions)

And just released there is a new tool called [BTSG NoS Addin](http://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/05/what-is-btsg-nos-addin-purpose-and-what-features-are-available-part-4/) will find your external dependencies.

Comment: I didn't think of this, but this is actually a very nice tool with a clear dependency listing on a lot of artifacts. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can check this using Admin Console of Biztalk.
For example if you want to know where a pipeline is used, just right click on pipeline and click on 'view dependencies' and now you can view all those places where pipeline is being used/refered. click on Number and it will bring to that place

Comment: I cannot find this function in Biztalk 2006R2, is it in Biztalk 2010 or higher? thanks.